# Apache configuration for two applications on same server

Tags: angular, apache, spring-boot

I have two separate applications for frontend and backend that can be deployed on linux or windows.

The front is build with angular and I deploy what resulted in the dist folder.
The back is a spring boot application where the war is launched without tomcat.
It's a small application that is not meant to be put on different server.

Lets assume we have the folder like this :

```
/path/to/apps/
             /conf/ (external conf for back.war)
             /front/
             back.war
```

I would like to have :

- `<my-ip>/front`  ==> /path/to/apps/front/index.html
- `<my-ip>/back`   ==> localhost:8080/back

I'm an early beginer with apache. I saw many things about VirtualHost, .htaccess or proxypass but couldn't really get something to work as I wanted.

Comment: Run FE on port 3030, BE on port 3040, bring nginx server and map /front -> localhost:3030, /back -> localhost:3040

Comment: Thank you and but I realize I didn't precise in the first place that it also need to be available on windows. I saw nginx server is considered beta on windows and for the moment can't be run as service. So it's a thing I'd rather keep as last resort.